# How to check the values of multiple dynamic radio buttons in a form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I am trying to make a quiz system. I have created dynamic radio buttons. Now I want to check the values of selected radio buttons. How can I do that?

```
 function createquestionpaper(qlist)
    {
        var questionform = $('#quesform');
        var quesNum = 1;
        $.each(qlist, function (index, val) {
            var questionstring = '<div class="form-group" ><label class="control-label" id="'+val.Question_ID+'">'+quesNum+'. '+val.Question1+'</label>'+
                                  '<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="'+val.Question_ID+'" value="1">'+val.Option1+'</div>' +
                                   '<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="' + val.Question_ID + '" value="2">' + val.Option2 + '</div>' +
                                  '<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="' + val.Question_ID + '" value="3">' + val.Option3 + '</div>' +
                                  '<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="' + val.Question_ID + '" value="4">' + val.Option4 + '</div>' +
                                  '</div><hr>';
            questionform.append(questionstring);
            quesNum = quesNum + 1;

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the other answers didn't mention a solution for checking all values at the same time:

```
// right answers
var solutions = [1,3,1,1,2,3,4];
// all answers from all questions (get all checked radio-inputs, then get all values)
var valuesForAllQuestions = $('.form-group', '#quesform').find('input:radio:checked').map(function() {return $(this).val()}).get();
// map them to points (1=correct answer, 0=false), then reduce it to a sum
var correct = valuesForAllQuestions.map((answer, idx)=>(answer==solutions[idx]?1:0)).reduce((sum, actual)=>sum+actual,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over `$('input[type=radio]:checked')`

```js
$('#done').on('click', function() {
  $('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function() {
    console.log('Question:', this.name, 'Answer:', this.value)
  });
});
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Question 1</h3>
1. <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" />
2. <input type="radio" name="q1" value="2" />
3. <input type="radio" name="q1" value="3" />
4. <input type="radio" name="q1" value="4" />
<h3>Question 2</h3>
1. <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" />
2. <input type="radio" name="q2" value="2" />
3. <input type="radio" name="q2" value="3" />
4. <input type="radio" name="q2" value="4" />
<h3>Question 3</h3>
1. <input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" />
2. <input type="radio" name="q3" value="2" />
3. <input type="radio" name="q3" value="3" />
4. <input type="radio" name="q3" value="4" />
<button id="done">Done</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery selectors to figure out which one is selected and retrieve its value:

```
$('input[name=yourQuestionID]:checked').val()
```

Comment: so i need to make array of QuestionID and then loop through that array for checked value?

Comment: If you want all selected inputs: `$('.form-group').find('input:radio:checked')`